# webview searchbar appear after a link to the same page

Tags: android, search, webview, ip-address

My application has a webview without any searchtool, like a fullscreen mode.
When i clik on a link, the search bar with the address of the site appear. 
How can i hide it ? I would like to continue in fullscreen mode.

Answer (score 0):

I finaly found something interesting here :

http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

in the section "handling page navigation"

I'll make some tests.

Comment: Good it was simply a line ! : webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());